# MySQL query. Creating a table displaying information by month and week

Tags: mysql, sql

please tell me how the query should be compiled for the table with the following lines: January 2019, first week of January 2019, second week of January 2019 ... fifth week of January 2019, February 2019, first week of February, 2019 second week of February 2019 .... Fifth week of December 2019. The amount of goods sold will be displayed in columns. That is, in the line of the month - the number of sales for the whole month, in the line of the week - the number of sold only for this week.

Comment: What do you call a week (mon-sun,sun-sat 1st to 6th)?

Comment: For simplicity, can take from 1 - 7, 8-15 etc

Comment: Are you allowed to use Excel pivot tables for this?

Comment: Not sure, but with pivot tables its pretty easy)